# Delete a word from a string in mysql row

Tags: php

Am trying to delete a word from a string in my database

The string is `$keywords = tech,sms,libya,tax`

Suppose i want to remove libya from the string how do i go about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think for the clarity you might want to explode the string into an array, remove the unwanted element and then reconstruct the string. Like this:

```
$keywords = 'tech,sms,libya,tax';       // Set String
$keywords = explode(',', $keywords);    // Explode into array
unset($keywords[ array_search('libya', $keywords) ]);   // Unset the array element with value of 'libya'
$keywords = implode(',',$keywords);     // Reconstruct string
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL's [REPLACE](http://davidwalsh.name/mysqls-replace-phps-strreplace) function.